# Is it safe to pass pointer to std::pair as a pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, pointers

Can I safely assume that an address of the first element of a `std::pair` can be used as an address of two element array? Of course both elements of the pair are of the same type. Following code works in g++ 7.2, clang 3.8 and vc++14

```
void foo(int* a)
{
    std::cout << std::to_string(a[0]) << ", " << std::to_string(a[1]) << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::pair<int, int> bar(42, 24);
    foo(&bar.first);
    return 0;
}
```

As `std::pair` is rather simple class I am convinced that this case can be generalized, but I'm not sure to what extent. For example, does it being a template class have any impact on the question?

If I cannot safely do that, why? If it's considered a valid code, what guarantees this?

Comment: why dont you pass the pair? Even if this was portable code (i hope not) it would be unneccesarily obfuscated

Comment: @user463035818 this is for the call of a function in a third-party library. Specifically [opencv `calcHist`](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html?#calchist)

Comment: you use `minMaxIdx` to find min and max of the array that is made up by the two entries of a pair? There are easier ways to do that

Comment: @user463035818 wrong link, sorry, see edit to the above comment

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are not allowed to, but I'd have to check back with the standard to give a definitive answer.

Comment: What is the reason you want to use `std::pair` instead of `std::array`?

Comment: Why not make an array and pass that to comply with 3rd party library param? `int arr[2] = {bar.first, bar.second}; foo(arr);`

Comment: It is generally not allowed to read beyond object boundaries. While a single variable can be considered an array of length 1 (so that `a[0]` is allowed by virtue of its definition as `*(a+0)`), reading its non-existing "second element" via `a[1]` is undefined behavior because it reads beyond `bar.first`'s boundaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cpp reference is not saying anything how the the templated struct std::pair has to be defined (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair).
It is not guaranteed, that the first and second parameter will be packed together. Even though most implementations will probably look like

```
template<class A, class B>
struct pair {
    [...]
    A first;
    B second;
    [...]
}
```

For int your code **might** work. For other types it is a very unsafe to assume how the internals of std::pair looks like.

If you need an array of integers of the elements, you have to copy them into a separate location.

Comment: Given your suggested implementation it would already be unsafe for homogenous types to assume that they are sequentially aligned (as padding might still occur). Which is why these kind of operations are generally UB

Comment: As I said for __integer__ it might work as they should never be padded. Please correct me if I&#39;m wrong.

But yes, I should have mentioned padding explicitely

Comment: AFAIK nowhere in the standard there is such requirement. Also as pointed out by Peter A. Schneider accessing another element (by pretending that it is an array) is already UB. It *might* work, but the code is ill-formed according to the standard

Comment: I suppose that `struct pair {
    [...]
    B second; A first;
    [...]
}` would be a compliant implementation.

Answer (score 4):

Making my comment into an answer:

It is categorically not allowed to read beyond object boundaries, except for arrays (as MSalters pointed out). While a single variable can be considered an array of length 1 (so that `a[0]` is allowed by virtue of its definition as `*(a+0)`), reading its non-existing "second element" via `a[1]` is undefined behavior because it reads beyond `bar.first`'s boundaries. That both objects are probably part of a larger aggregate object (whose implementation is unknown) does not change that.

Note that many boundary transgressions like this one work, with known architectures, compilers, libraries, and compiler options; this particular one should work everywhere because `int` is designed to have the natural word size on a given machine and can thus be aligned without padding in a struct, which a `std::pair` certainly will be; but there is no guarantee, including malicious compilers. In fact, the program as it is presented (namely as one translation unit) can statically be proven ill-formed. A compiler could detect that and reject compilation.

Comment: You're not reading past object boundaries; the whole object is `std::pair<T,T>`. That's not a "probably", that's the premise of the question. Reading past sub-object boundaries is fine, that happens all the time with arrays. Your conclusion might be right, but the arguments seem iffy. I think you need to be more specific about the relation between sub-objects and the whole object; arrays and structures are different.

Comment: @MSalters You give the answer: Arrays and structures are different. Inside arrays you can move to the next subobject. Inside structs you cannot, probably because the language designers want to preserve opaqueness. An array, by contrast, has a defined layout.

Comment: The standard never says that you can't read beyond an object boundary, if there is in fact another object at the next location

Comment: @M.M Can you provide a quote? (The way you word it I could `void f(){ static int a,b; printf("%d", *(&a+1); }` with most compilers, and it is not UB? (Or perhaps `*(&a-1)`, depending on whatever.)

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider: That's two *unrelated* objects. Structure members are related, by virtue of being sub-objects of the same object. And an object is allocated contiguously in memory. Arrays are further restricted in that they are allocated contiguously, with sub-objects (elements) allocated in order of their array index. It's the latter condition which allows pointer arithmetic on arrays.

Comment: @MSalters Re "That's two unrelated objects": True; but M.M's comment provided an unconditional "if there is **another** object" (emphasis mine). So we need to establish what kind of relationship between objects allows access from one to another. Subobjects in arrays permit it without doubt; I do not think it is allowed in structs. By the way, is the order of elements in a struct/class (hello Lightspeed) not also in the order of declaration? At least the first element is specified to be positioned at the beginning of the struct, I thought.

Comment: More like `if ( &a + 1 == &b ) printf("%d", *(&a + 1));`  , there isn't any text in the standard that says this is UB ... I'm not sure whether it's intended to be correct or UB (or if the committee aren't sure either).  This discussion is probably getting out of hand for the comments section, my main point is that (unlike C) the C++ standard never describes the past-the-end pointer as not being dereferencable, it seems to deliberately leave the topic vague

Comment: @M.M Well, the C++11 standard is pretty unambiguous. [expr.add], 5: *"If both the pointer operand and the result point to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; **otherwise, the behavior is
undefined**.* (Emphasis mine. And *"For the purposes of these operators, a pointer to a nonarray object behaves the same as a pointer to the
first element of an array of length one with the type of the object as its element type."*)

Comment: @M.M. Of course, if we are concerned about overflow (probably in a segmented memory architecture?), the fact that both integers are in the same struct relieves us of our worries. But the emphasized wording is clear.

Comment: @M.M. On the other hand, of course I'm free to use some magic number which I happen to know through insight into machine or compiler, convert it to a pointer, and access that memory, knowing it is valid. But I suppose for it to be valid C++ one would need to go through a true integer value with appropriate casts. (That informs the compiler to assume aliasing, for example.)

Comment: @M.M. Oh, and note that the UB stems from the addition alone; no dereferencing needed.

Comment: The text you quoted says that `&a + 1` is OK, it's a "one past the last element of the array object" (with the nonarray object behaving like an array of length one as explained there)

Comment: @M.M Good catch for this particular case, true (but don't try it with triplets!); now the question is whether you can dereference it. If the address were a number I think yes (as with any embedded system with e.g. fix hardware addresses). If the address is -- like it is here -- derived from another subobject I'm not sure, at least because of aliasing issues (the compiler needs not assume that you read an object through a pointer to another object, and may not update cashes, respect the order of operations etc.). So perhaps you must cast to an integer and back ...